# how to print a document via blackberry7

Tags: blackberry

I am new to mobile technology programming. Tried to search on below issue but could not get expected result.
Can someone please tell me which API should be used to show print dialog box and to print a document or output via blackberry 7?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct printing support provided by BlackBerry OS 7, or in fact, any BlackBerry OS level that I am aware of at this time.

There are applications that support printing, but my understanding is that these work by installing drivers for the attached printer (usually Bluetooth).  So you should look for a printer that is supported on the Blackberry platform and then you can use it directly in your application.